# How to take all text field values to temporary array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, model, tableview, cell

I fairly new in Swift.
So I created numbers of sections based on the user input, and then I want to get all the data from the text fields.
1 section contains 4 rows (4 text fields).
Next I want to do something with the data from each section.

Here's what the app look like:

[image]

Now as I mentioned before, the number of sections can be different based on user request.
Here I have created `Struct` and temporary Array like so:

```
struct LabelData {
     var lbl1: Int
     var lbl2: Int
     var lbl3: Int
     var lbl4: Int
}
var txtFieldArray = [LabelData]()
```

then in `cellForRow` I put this:

```
txtFieldValue?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sectionTxtFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
```

and here's the function:

```
var row1: Int = 0
var row2: Int = 0
var row3: Int = 0
var row4: Int = 0

@objc func sectionTxtFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
    for rowIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1 {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CellOutlet
        if rowIndex == 0 {
            row1 = Int(cell.txtFieldSpecNumb.text!) ?? 0
        }
        
        else if rowIndex == 1 {
            row2 = Int(cell.txtFieldSpecNumb.text!) ?? 0
        }
        
        else if rowIndex == 2 {
            row3 = Int(cell.txtFieldSpecNumb.text!) ?? 0
        }
        
        else if rowIndex == 3 {
            row4 = Int(cell.txtFieldSpecNumb.text!) ?? 0
        }
        }
    }

@IBAction func btnShowResult(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let x = LabelData(lbl1: row1, lbl2: row2, lbl3: row3, lbl4: row4)
    txtFieldArray.append(x)
    // print array
    print(txtFieldArray)
}
```

with input in first section = 1,2,3,4;
it resulted just fine, like this:

```
[(lbl1: 1, lbl2: 2, lbl3: 3, lbl4: 4)]
```

But that's for 1 section. what if I had more than 1 section.
In that case, I also put into `var` before I add it to `LabelData` and append it to Array.
How can I do this better?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways that could improve the provided code (e.g. creating a subclass of `UITextField` with an `IndexPath` property) but it would fall under **opinion-based**. To answer your specific question, I'd recommend getting rid of `row1`, `row2`, `row3` & `row4` as they are redundant (you already have `txtFieldArray` for data storage and access).

In your `cellForRow`, add the following line

```
cell.txtFieldValue?.tag = indexPath.section
```

Then, update your `sectionTxtFieldDidChange` to something like this

```
@objc func sectionTxtFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let section = sender.tag
    for rowIndex in 0...4 { //assuming there are always 4 rows in a section
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: section)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CellOutlet

        if rowIndex == 0 {
            txtFieldArray[section].lbl1 = Int(cell.txtFieldSpecNumb.text!) ?? 0
        } else if rowIndex == 1 {
            txtFieldArray[section].lbl2 = Int(cell.txtFieldSpecNumb.text!) ?? 0
        } else if rowIndex == 2 {
            txtFieldArray[section].lbl3 = Int(cell.txtFieldSpecNumb.text!) ?? 0
        } else if rowIndex == 3 {
            txtFieldArray[section].lbl4 = Int(cell.txtFieldSpecNumb.text!) ?? 0
        }
    }
}
```

This way, each item in your `txtFieldArray` would represent each section where `lbl1`, `lbl2` `lbl3` & `lbl4` of each item would represent the respective rows

**NOTE:** Make sure that `txtFieldArray` is initialised and has an entry for each of the section before you start editing the text fields

**UDPATE:** Based on the information provided in the comments, you can pre-populate your `txtFieldArray` as below right after you have your user input stored in `finalSectionNumber`

```
txtFieldArray = (0...finalSectionNumber).map { _ in LabelData(lbl1: 0, lbl2: 0, lbl3: 0, lbl4: 0) }
```

Comment: I have been thinking about ur note, but I had initialized it `var txtFieldArray = [LabelData]()` after the `struct`
Yet I still have an error of `Index out of range`
what happened here?

Comment: You also need to pre-populate it with an entry for each section. In your `numberOfSections` method, how do you determine the number of sections?

Comment: In number of sections, I returned this: `return finalSectionNumber + 1`.
`finalSectionNumber` is the user input of how many section they desire, and the `+1` is for the button section. How do I create that entry point for each section?

Comment: it's now working, it was able to print the input (for ex: 1,2,3,4), but then the code u just add making the initial data always there. like this: `[(lbl1: 1, lbl2: 2, lbl3: 3, lbl4: 4), (lbl1: 0, lbl2: 0, lbl3: 0, lbl4: 0)]`.
I had to remove the 0,0,0,0 data first.
I put the code after the finalSectionNumber like this:
`var finalSectionNumber: Int = 0 { didSet {txtFieldArray = (0...finalSectionNumber).map { _ in WSspecData(lbl1: 0, lbl2: 0, lbl3: 0, lbl4: 0) }}}`.
Or did I put it wrong?